# Let $f: A\rightarrow B, g: B\rightarrow C, and h: C\rightarrow D$. If $f$ and $g$ are both injective, then $g\circ f$ is injective.

Tags: functions, solution-verification

Proof:
Assume that $f$ and $g$ are injective. Let $a_1,a_2\in A$ and $b_1=f(a_1), b_2=f(a_2)$.
Suppose that $g(f(a_1))=g(f(a_2))\Rightarrow g(b_1)=g(b_2)\Rightarrow b_1=b_2$ ($g$ is injective) $\Rightarrow f(a_1)=f(a_2)\Rightarrow a_1=a_2$ ($f$ is injective).

Therefore, $g\circ f$ is injective.

$\blacksquare$

Comment: The main proof seems alright to me. But what is $h?$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ideas of the proof are solid, but the presentation needs a little work. Here's a possible revision. I've used strikethrough for deleted bits, and italic for added stuff, except in the displayed equations.

Proof:
<del>Assume that</del> $f$ and $g$ are injective *by hypothesis*.

*To show $g \circ f$ injective, we'll suppose that $(g\circ f)(a_1) = (g\circ f)(a_2)$ and conclude that $a_1 = a_2$.*

Let $a_1,a_2\in A$ and $b_1=f(a_1), b_2=f(a_2)$.

Suppose that $g(f(a_1))=g(f(a_2))$. Then* <del>\Rightarrow</del>

\begin{align}
g(b_1)&=g(b_2) & \text{by substitution;} \\
b_1& =b_2 & \text{ because $g$ is injective;}\\
f(a_1)& =f(a_2) & \text{substitution again;} \\
a_1 &=a_2 & \text{because $f$ is injective.}
\end{align}

Therefore, $g\circ f$ is injective.

$\blacksquare$

---

You could easily get rid of the introductory italic line, but it helps the reader know what's coming up.

In *your* writeup, there are a lot of run-on sentences. Using the "two column" format can help avoid those.

Comment: Thank you. I've always thought that my proofs are correct but the presentation is not good.